# Passed props not changing

Tags: reactjs, state

im new to react, and therefore this might be a missunderstanding of a concept, rather than a programming error.

My Problem is the following:
In my parent component i pass a variable and its change function to my child component via props. When i then use the change function to change the variable, it seems to work. When i conmsole.log the variable value in my parent component, the new value seems to be correctly set. But when i console.log the variable passed as prop in my child component, it awlays stays outputs the initial state (test2436).
So my guess is, that either the value is not set correctly in the frist place, or the props are not updated. Can something tell me, that my mistake is?

Parent component:

```
import Input from './input.js';
import Graph from './graph.js';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  sharedData = "test2436";

  setSharedData = (val) =>{
    console.log("bef+"+this.sharedData);
    this.sharedData = val;
    console.log("aft"+this.sharedData);
    //this logs the new value correctly
  }
  
  componentDidMount = function () {
    console.log(this.sharedData);
  }

  render() {

    return <div className="App">
      <label key={this.sharedData}>{this.sharedData}</label>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/graph" component={Graph} />
          <Route path="/" render={() => (<Input data={this.sharedData} change={this.setSharedData} />)} exact />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  }
}

export default App;
```

Child component

```
import React from "react";


class Input extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { value: "" };
        this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);
        this.processInput = this.processInput.bind(this);
        console.log(props);
        this.handler = this.props.change;
    }
    
    handleInput(event) {
        this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
        console.log(this.props);
        this.handler(event.target.value);
        //console.log("after"+this.props.data);
    }

    
    processInput(event) {
    //unimporant code
    }

    render() {
        return <form>
            <textarea onChange={this.handleInput} id="inputData" rows="20" cols="180">
            </textarea><p>
                <button type='button' onClick={this.processInput} >Analyze</button></p></form>
    }
}

export default Input;
```

I've heard that using state is the prefered method for passing data.
If i manage to get it to work, is this considered a bad practice?
Are there better ways to pass data, that dont take long to implement? I dont want to lern redux or something similar yet, since i'm still learning react :)

Thank you for your replies.

**edit:**
I've managed to get the new props via the getDerivedStateFromProps function. That solves my problem for now, but my other questions are still open.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store `sharedData` in the `state` object for your class component and using `setState` to update it like the code below.

(I reduced the code to whatever is needed let me know if you need more details)

```
class App extends React.Component {

    state = {
        sharedData: "test2436"
    }

    setSharedData = (val) => {
        this.setState({sharedData: val})
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <Input data={this.state.sharedData} change={this.setSharedData} />
        )
    }
}
```

**edit:** fixed syntax errors

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, i understand the principle. So just to clarify: Passing a variable (other than the state object) as prop will not cause the prop to update if a new value is assigned to the variable. If i want my prop to automatically update to variable changes, i have to use the state object. Is that correct? If so, do you know, why normal variables as props wont update automatically, but the state object will?

Comment: You are correct, react only keeps track to update the data within `state` (at least in this scope, there is also context and redux state etc. but these are more advanced use cases), react would not know to update any data not stored in the `state` variable even if you manually change it, let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank your for your quick reply, i have a better understanding of if now. btw: i'm pretty sure that you need to use a : instead of = in your state initialisation and remove the semicolon.